# Completely uninstall/reinstall Eclipse and add support for php and jquery

Tags: eclipse

I have been using Eclipse a short while and it worked perfectly until I started downloading different plugins that I didn't really need. Now I get a ton of different errors and can't even open a php file.

What I want to do is just to remove Eclipse and reinstall it, but that was much harder that I first thought. I marked every `eclipse` package in `synaptic packaged manager` and selected `complete removal`, I even deleted the `.meta` folder in my working dictionary, but when I installed eclipse again. It was as if I hadn't removed anything. Same errors from the `plug-ins` I had installed before.

Seems like when you install something in linux, files are stored all over the place. Makes real hard do remove anything. So how do I COMPLETELY remove Eclipse, reinstall it and add support for `php` and `jquery`.

Thanks.

Comment: i tried the purge. it did not remove eclipse from my system but reset it to newly installed state. not quite was i was expecting but certainly what i was looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe all plugins go into the .eclipse/plugins folder in your home directory. So...

```
sudo apt-get purge eclipse
rm -r ~/.eclipse/
```

should completely remove it from your system.  I haven't tried it as I don't want to lose my installation :)

You should be able to get PHP and jQuery using Aptana Studio.  I was able to get 1.5 to work as a repository (from Help > Install New Software) using http://update15.aptana.org/studio/26124/ and a Google search, but I haven't tried installing 2.0 which you can get from here: http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2/download

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse*; rm -r ~/.eclipse/; #this will get rid of the dependencies that were autoinstalled during eclipse installation

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse install is fairly touchy.  It can store things in places other than just `.meta`.  I typically don't recommend getting source files from places, but I would recommend that you to go Eclipse's site and download the prepackaged zip/tar that has the features that you want (they have i think 8 different packagings of eclipse with various plugins, you should be able to find one that does PHP and jquery).  Note that you can later expand on the one package by adding additional plugins for additional functionality.

***EDIT***
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php  <--- that's the site for the Eclipse IDE (which I assume you are using).  I do not see a plugin for JQuery that's prepackaged, but that doesnt mean you can't get what you need from the plugins.  Just don't go downloading plugins you don't need, because sometimes you can break your install of Eclipse that way.