# Eclipse "clean" reinstall unable to update

Tags: 11.10, eclipse

I managed to botch up my eclipse installation by installing a plugin (MOTODEV studio).  In an attempt to fix the problem I decided to go ahead and do a full reinstall of Eclipse.  I followed the suggestion in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31846/completely-uninstall-reinstall-eclipse-and-add-support-for-php-and-jquery) post to remove eclipse and delete the plugins.  I also completely deleted my workspace folder to get rid of any configuration files there since all my projects were just tutorial programs.

The exact issue I'm having:

- Help > Check for Updates
- Some updates are listed but at the top of the dialog box just below "Available Updates" it says: "The operation cannot be completed.  See the details"
- Under details it says "There were no installable units selected when the plan was computed."
- If I select the listed updates and attempt to install them then I get the error: "Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency."

I think it must be an issue with some relics of the previous installation but I'm not sure where else to look for files to delete so I can get a clean start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured this out; the problem is that you need to run Eclipse as root, because Eclipse needs to write in the install directory to update. An alternative (which i did) is to chown  all files in the eclipse install directory to your user.

/Mike

Comment: Thank you!  I honestly can't believe it didn't occur to me to try sudo when having problems INSTALLING something!  Even if it was built into the application and not a stand alone installer.  Thanks so much for the help.