# Eclipse Java perspective not showing after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, java, eclipse

I upgraded my ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10, eclipse was working like a charm, but after the upgrade, the java perspective is not visible any more, moreover, I cannot create a java project. Any idea why this happened, I tried to rename the java ~/.eclipse to ~/.eclipse.old but this didn't help. 
Thank you

Comment: have you installed jdk??

Comment: yup: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-source openjdk-7-demo openjdk-7-doc openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib`

Comment: But anw, shouldn't be there even if I upgrade ?

Comment: did you configure in Preferences?

Comment: If not then follow these steps -> Open Eclipse -> Window menu -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE -> If you see name OpenJDK & its path then good else follow these steps -> Click Add -> Select Standard VM -> for JRE home : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 -> Finish -> Restart your Eclipse

Comment: @DpN Java is not an option in preference, it doesn't appear anywhere in the preference window.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14274/discussion-between-dpn-and-amir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. Here's how I fixed it.

Uninstall all eclipse related packages.

```
sudo apt-get remove eclipse-*
```

Install again using this answer:

[How to completely uninstall eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282951/how-to-completely-uninstall-eclipse)