# Eclipse complete uninstall from ubuntu 15.10

Tags: eclipse

I installed eclipse-java-neon-M3-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz on ubuntu 15.10 by following steps given in response to [How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse) but now want to completely uninstall it,
 how to do that? Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely uninstall eclipse?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/282951/how-to-completely-uninstall-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed the above link accurately, then to uninstall it, do the following:

Goto the installed folder:

```
cd /opt && ls | grep eclipse
```

It will output the name of a folder that says `eclipse`. Copy the name of that folder.

Now, type the following command to delete it:

```
sudo rm -rf PASTE THE NAME OF THE FOLDER HERE

sudo rm /usr/local/bin/eclipse44

sudo rm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm

sudo find / -type f -iname eclipse.desktop -delete

sudo rm -rf ~/.eclipse
```

If you do not need java anymore, then:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk*
```

Also, if you want to remove your saved projects, then, browse for the folder where you saved it, by default it's in `~/workspaces` and type the following:

```
sudo rm -rf DRAG AND DROP THE FOLDER HERE
```

**EDIT**: As pointed by [simran-kumari](https://askubuntu.com/users/487492/simran-kumari), the plugins still remain after the above process of purging eclipse. To remove the plugins, browse to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/missioncontrol/` and delete the relevant files/folders. The command for that is:

```
sudo find /usr/ -type d -iname '*eclipse*' -delete && sudo find /usr/ -type f -iname '*eclipse*' -delete
```

Comment: to remove additional plugins (without jdk cleanup) after following above steps  cleared the plugins folder from jvm folder and then a complete uninstall is success.

Comment: Couldn't get you?

Comment: Following your steps worked perfectly but when I reinstalled a different version of eclipse the plugins which I  added in my earlier eclipse were automatically detected and installed in the fresh installation (along with notification this happened) So again I uninstalled it with the above steps and looked for the residue content and found it in jvm /lib folder...........so in case if anyone follows complete steps along with removing jdk  complete uninstallation is done automatically but if someone wants to keep jdk then will have to this (plugins removal) manually.

Comment: Can you please tell me the path to the folder and name of it so that I can edit the answer and add your solution.

Comment: folder path is . "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/missioncontrol/"