# How dangerous is `sudo apt-get autoremove package*`?

Tags: apt, package-management, eclipse

I was deleting all previous Eclipse versions [as per an answer I read](https://askubuntu.com/a/286228/467883), so I used `sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse*`. It said it would be about 40 Mb of files to uninstall, so I agreed believing it would work on the intended scope.

The expected behavior is that it removes the application itself and also its dependencies. In my case, it's begun to delete some `linux-headers`, `python` packages, etc. which I don't think are related to Eclipse, and it's got me worried. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not dangerous at all. From [man apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-get.8.html):

```
autoremove (and the auto-remove alias since 1.1)
    autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
    installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no
    longer needed.
```

Comment: From that description, I guess nothing important was removed even though so many `linux-headers` and important-sounding stuff flied across the screen. Thanks, I'll look into the behavior of the `package*` argument.

Comment: Exactly. The `linux-headers` and other packages are probably from old kernels, no longer in use. And the `package*` argument is pattern matching which means "anything that starts with 'package'".