# How to uninstall eclipse from /root

Tags: permissions, eclipse

Using Eclipse installer I erroneously installed it on `/root` directory (default path) using `sudo` to run `eclipse-inst`:
[image]
As shown here:
[image]
Not even a `.desktop` file was created. After [learning about `/root`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187997/i-cant-access-the-root-folder) and [how to install Eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/a/145018/411689) I decided I want to uninstall it to do it properly. But if I shouldn't change `/root` permission, how can I safely remove eclipse?

Using

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse
```

returns

```
Package 'eclipse' is not installed, so not removed
```

Comment: How did you install it?  You mention 'eclipse' installer - so use it's reversal procedure.  `sudo apt-get remove|purge..` is for removing packages installed with the `dpkg|apt` install procedure(s); so it can't reverse a procedure it didn't do.  Look at your 'eclipse' installer & follow it's uninstall recommendations.

Comment: I looked over eclipse installer and it didn't have any uninstall instructions (at least what I looked so far). Could you please provide an example on how uninstall eclipse by its own installer?

Comment: I've never used eclipse, so have no idea how it's installed, or more important how you installed it.  Either way it's just the reverse of whatever procedure you used; ie. apt-get remove if you apt-get installed it, if it was installed by a script; view the script to see what it did and do the reverse, if installed from tarball & compiled with .. ie. however you installed it; just do the reverse..  If it was the link you provided (which had 18 answers), the reverse of a `cp` is a `rm`, likewise the reverse of a `ln` is also a `rm`.. etc

Comment: Trying to open eclipse script resulted into a corrupted text file. How can I retrieve the correct script text file?

Comment: I don't know how you installed it; so I really can't help. I use commands for everything, as that way I have `history` showing what I did (mine also records date & time of commands which isn't the default..) so I'd look back in `history` to see where I `wget` the file from, so I could re-run the `wget` (download), let alone commands used to install something.  `apt` & `dpkg` commands are logged in /var/log/apt/, but you didn't use those tools, so use whatever method you have to audit/record/documentation your work.. You should know, esp. if you want to become a dev/sysadmin/...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this thread to solve your issues but you need to remove purge not only eclipse but all related packages...

[Read this...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282951/how-to-completely-uninstall-eclipse)